# Is there a way to recursively get all employee in a department hierarchy?

Tags: sql

Let's say that the company has a number of department and each department also has a sub-department, the structure like a hierarchy tree. I have tables like these:

```
employee
  - id, name, ..., position_id, department_id
```

```
department
  - id, name, ..., child_id
```

```
departmentToChildDepartment (many-2-many)
  - department_id, child_department_id
```

The question is how to get all employee that in a specific department and its child.

For example, if `Production` department has Team A and Team B as sub-department, by inputting `Production` department id I can get all employee in `Production`, Team A and Team B.

In which

```
SELECT * 
FROM employee 
WHERE department_id = <Production_Department_Id>
```

is not working because it will not get employee from Team A and Team B.

Comment: Tag only the database that you use.

Comment: b b b but I use both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, I believe, the schema of department table needs to be modified as follows (deptid, name, ..., parent_deptid). With the structure you had specified, it will lead to data redundancy for mapping each child department with parent department.

Thus, considering the perspective, I will first target the first parent dept as level 0, (first parent department will have the parent_deptId as NULL) and it's respective hierarchy in iterative order.

```
WITH dept_cte AS 
(
    SELECT 
        deptId, deptName, 0 AS level
    FROM 
        department 
    WHERE 
        ISNULL(parent_deptId, 0) = 0 
        AND deptId = @YourTopLevelDepartment

    UNION ALL 

    SELECT 
        d.deptId, d.deptName, dc.level + 1
    FROM 
        department d
    INNER JOIN 
        dept_cte dc ON d.parent_deptId = dc.deptId
)
SELECT 
    E.empId, E.empName, T.deptId, T.deptName
FROM 
    employee E 
INNER JOIN 
    dept_cte T ON e.deptId = T.depId
```